# 40 GHz spectrum analyzer with N-type coax input?

Tags: rf, microwave, spectrum-analyzer, coax, cutoff-frequency

We have an old Rohde & Schwarz FSEK 30 that is advertised as having a range from 20 Hz to 40 GHz, with an N-type input connector.  My conundrum is that a type-N connector with air dielectric should have a maximum frequency of approximately 19 GHz before the primary TEM-mode propagation is joined by the TE11-mode. From MIL-STD-348A the inner and outer coax diameters are 0.12 and 0.2759 inches, respectively.  According to [Microwaves101](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/coax) the cutoff wavelength for the TE11-mode in an air dielectric coax is $$\lambda_c = \pi\frac{D+d}{2}$$
where D is the outer diameter in meters and d in the inner diameter in meters.

This disconnect between the theoretical frequency limit of an N-type and the stated range of the instrument has me doubting the validity of measurements made above 19 GHz.  Can anyone shed light on this mystery?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Maybe the manufacturer can...

Comment: You're probably meant to use a different cable with adapter immediately in front of the instrument's input at high frequencies.  Also check the fine print to see what attenuation it is really promising at 40 GHz.

Comment: Is the coax air core?  Maybe look up some RF cable manufacturer's and see what they spec for cable with N-type connector

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The R&S instruments are equipped with female [test port adapters](http://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/application_notes/1ma100/1MA100_3e_port_conn_sys_test_port_adapter_sys.pdf).

Edit: [archived pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20151117222816/http://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/application_notes/1ma100/1MA100_4e_RS_testport_adapter_system.pdf)

[image]

You can replace the N type with a more suitable type for higher frequencies.

[image]

Comment: Link is bad....

Comment: @rsaxvc archived link added, original retained